# cont add foreignkey

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to create two tables and wanted to link them with the help of foreign key

but it says error in the 2nd table. Can you edit my syntax and solve the issues...

syntax:

```
create table test1 (
    id int not null , 
    name varchar(25) , 
    constraint pk_tst1_id primary key (id)
);
```

> query executed successfully, table created with no errors...

2nd table

syntax:

```
create table test2(
    projectid int , 
    projectname varchar(25) , 
    creater varchar(25),
    constraint pk_tst2_id primary key (projectid),
    constraint fk_tst2_ctr foreign key (creater) references test1 (name)
);
```

> [error:"Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_tst2_ctr' in the referenced table 'test1'".]

I want to mention 1 thing, yesterday I have uploaded an issue(question) in SQL, please look at it and if you know please give me a way to rectify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key should be to the **primary key**:

```
create table test2 (
    projectid int,
    projectname varchar(25),
    creater int,
    constraint pk_tst2_id primary key (projectid),
    constraint fk_tst2_ctr foreign key (creater) references test1 (id)
);
```

When you want the name, you would use `JOIN` to look up the name.